# How do I count the total number of lines of files in a given directory? in python

Tags: python

How can I use Python to count the total number of lines in the files in a given directory?

Comment: How have you tried to solve this problem so far?

Comment: What would make *anyone* think this is a school assignment? Anybody at all might be interested in the number of lines in the files in a directory for a *huge* variety of reasons... The first question is much more appropriate though.

Comment: @Cpfohl Because anyone interested in that, would at least give it a very small try and say : *I have found this or that, but didn't understand such and such  etc..*  Instead this question is worded as a studend who don't really care about it, and just say "gimme the code" ( That's what it looks like, I'm not saying that's what IT IS )

Comment: @Cpfoh, Because of the "in python" requirement. Otherwise shell tools, eg `wc .* *` would be more suitable

Comment: I see your points, I guess I feel like from within a python script shell tools are more of a pain to work with than native python: I don't like python's subprocess module...I use native python wherever I can. Also, @Oscar, I find that 'gimme the code' is more indicative of a new S.O. user than a student.

Answer (score 5):

In pseudo-code (non-executable):

```
total_length = 0
file_list = fetch_file_list() 
# USE: os.walk or glob.glob depending on whether you want to filter the files.
for file_path in file_list:
    file_path = make_path_absolute(file_path)
    # This can be as simple as os.path.join(your_root_path, file_path)
    file_object = open(file_path) 
    # Don't forget there are different modes -- will all the files be text?
    total_length += length(file_object.readlines()) 
    # YOU MIGHT WANT TO CONSIDER: What if some of the files are large?
print "There are", length(file_list), "files in", \
    file_path, "containing", total_length, "lines of text."
```

Comment: Scary how pseudo looks the same as python ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Python OS](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) to get the list of files.

Comment: Mike, I'd recommend dropping the comment about school assignment.  It's rather insulting, and the question doesn't really suggest a school assignment as much as a basic question. Not all basic questions are homework.

Comment: ... and since when being a student is  insulting?  Is useful to know if a practical answer is needed, or a more detailed  one ( consider sorting, could be answered directly with the libraries, or helping in the sorting algorithm implementation )

Comment: It's insulting if you're *not* a student.  Asking if you're a student is fine, but that's more of a comment thing and should be done tactfully.